# Importing separate rows and columns from a .txt file into an excel worksheet(vba)

Tags: vba, excel

I have been following an example for importing .txt files into excel, the only problem is i can't seem to figure out how to make this line split the data into 2 separate columns

```
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = oFS.ReadLine
Loop
oFS.Close
```

The .txt file I need to import has 2 columns and N rows , my question is , how can I read it without both columns from the .txt file being written into 1 column on the excel worksheet?

```
N
X  Y
X2 Y2
X3 Y3
etc..
```

Thats how the .txt file must look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What separates the fields that need to go into two columns??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job, using VBA Split() function:

```
Sub sof20301663ImportTextFile()
  Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3

  Dim i, iup, varArray
  Dim fso As Object, tso As Object
  Dim strFilePath, strLine      

  ' adapt here your text file name:      '
  strFilePath = "MyTestFile.txt"

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")      '
  ' get TextStream:

  Set tso = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, ForReading)

  i = 2
  Do While Not tso.AtEndOfStream        '
    ' read a line from the file:
    strLine = tso.ReadLine
    ' split with separator tab:
    varArray = Split(strLine, vbTab)
    iup = UBound(varArray)
    ' split with separator space:

    If (iup <= 0) Then
      varArray = Split(strLine, " ")
      iup = UBound(varArray)
    End If

    ' fill a cell: using strLine as range address:

    strLine = "A" & i
    Range(strLine).Value = varArray(0)
    Range(strLine).NumberFormat = "General"

    ' if there is more then two words, fill cell 2:

    If (iup > 0) Then
      strLine = "B" & i
      Range(strLine).Value = varArray(1)
      Range(strLine).NumberFormat = "General"
    End If        
    i = i + 1

  Loop

  ' clean objects:

  tso.Close
  Set tso = Nothing

  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

#### Content of MyTestFile.txt:

```
50
info    computer
image   logo
tendancy    soulant
```

#### Excel Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply , works like a charm , commented sections really helpful for a newbie to VBA such as myself aswell. If i can only ask for 1 addition , where can I make a condition to import the data from the .txt file as numbers instead of text?

Comment: Happy to share something.

Comment: Yes , It handles them the same way , I didnt phrase myself correctly I think.Is there a way for the imported text, given it consists of numbers, to format the cells to not be of a Text type but of a Number one? Instead of manually formatting them after being imported , can it be done with some simple line of code?